# Does MmGetMdlVirtualAddress return user-mode virtual address or kernel-mode virtual address?

Tags: windows, operating-system

So if I call MmGetMdlVirtualAddress in a kernel-mode driver, would it give be system address space VA or the attached user-mode process VA?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Seems that based on this discussion it returns the user-mode VA that originated created this MDL:
https://community.osr.com/discussion/29488/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-between-mmgetmdlvirtualaddress-and-mmgetsystemaddressformdlsafe

EDIT:
However, I think this is not completely correct.  It should be working in the process context that the driver is running in.